# Illustrator: Process SVGs without resizing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have a simple SVG of shapes  that I wish to process using Adobe Illustrator (to merge some adjacent shapes). Unfortunately, when I save the processed shapes as SVG again, the size of the image has completely changed. This wouldn't matter in a plain image, but matters in this case because of its effect on the use of the path data down the line.

Is there a way of using Illustrator in a "do no damage" mode, where it doesn't modify the canvas or anything else unless specifically asked to?

I had a similar problem with Inkscape on Linux.

Comment: Do you mean filesize or the pixel size of the image? Do vector graphics even have a real "canvas size", or do they just have some sort of "preferred viewing size" attribute?

Comment: They have a scale. When I re-open the resulting image in a text editor, the given canvas size of 10cm x 4cm has been altered to something smaller. That means the paths no longer line up to other images.

Comment: Take a look at these two questions, they might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141023/exporting-as-an-svg-in-adobe-illustrator-canvas-size-issues, and http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9175/illustrator-cs6-change-artboard-size-final-saved-file-dimensions-to-match-bou